# Does one element of a field represent some other element of any arbitrary field?

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory

Three elements a,b,c of a field form an arithmetic progression if their successive difference are equal: b-a=c-b. Prove that b=a+c/2.
when I start proving it:
=> b-a+b=c-b+b
=> b+b-a=c
=> b+b-a+a=c+a
=> b+b=c+a
in next step, how I write b+b as 2b as it is not specified that b belongs to real number field. for example if F= {(a,b)| a,b belongs to R} where addition is defined as simple vector addition [(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)] and multiplication is defined as pairwise product[(a,b).(c,d)=(a.c,b.d)]
Then, (2,3)+(2,3) = (4,6) = (2,2).(2,3) not equal to 2.(2,3) and 2.(2,3) is also not defined. 
Does 2 in the above question is just a representation of corresponding "2" of an arbitrary field F or it represent something else? Please clarify this.

Comment: You post would become easier to read if you used $\LaTeX$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn’t a field because there are non-zero elements without multiplicative inverse, e.g. $(1,0)$.

The literal $2$ is generally taken to refer to the element $1+1$ of the field, where $1$ is the multiplicative identity. More generally, an integer is naturally associated with its image under the unique group homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to the additive group of the field that maps $1$ to $1$. Thus, $b+b=1\cdot b+1\cdot b=(1+1)\cdot b=2b$.

The problem is implicitly making the assumption that the [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)#Case_of_fields) of the field is not $2$, that is, that $2\ne0$, so that you can divide through by $2$.

Comment: But (1.b) may not be defined. Because while defining a field we define multiplication for the elements of that field and 1 may not belong to that field. I still have some doubt regarding using b+b=2b. Please claify

Comment: @Manu: I wrote "where $1$ is the multiplicative identity". Please read more carefully. It's common practice to denote the multiplicative identity of a field by $1$. If disambiguation is required, this can be written as $1_{\mathbb F}$, but since there is no integer or real number $1$ involved here, it's usual to omit such indices.

Comment: Ok. But one last question is b+b= b(1+1). Here 1 should be the multiplicative identity of that particular field to which B belongs not just of real number. Is this correct?

Comment: @Manu: Not just here. Every single $1$ written both in your question and in my answer refers to the multiplicative identity of the field under consideration. The real numbers don't enter into it.